# How to set the property of UITableViewHeaderFooterView from "viewForHeaderInSection" method of TableViewController in swift 4 IOS?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uitableview

I've **xib view** and **EditHeader** class as **UITableViewHeaderFooterView**  as below. I've created actions of two buttons. I've **closure properties** inside class. 
[image]

Now I want to access closure properties from **viewForHeaderInSection** method of **TableViewController** so that whenever button is clicked some action is done.But I'm not being able to **access the properties of EditHeader class**. Is there any solutions?
[image]

Answer (score 2):

You declared `headerView` as `UIView` (since that's what is getting returned from that delegate method).

Try declaring it this way:

```
case 1 :
    if let editHeader = 
        tableView.dequeueReusableHeaderFooterView(withIdentifier: "EditHeader") as? EditHeader 
    {
        editHeader.backgroundColor = UIColor.clear
        editHeader.editCardInfo = { }
        headerView = editHeader
    }
```

Comment: Very cleverly integrated into the OP's existing code!

Comment: Thank you @michael.